# Javascript Charts don't load until FWD then BACK

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a problem with the javascript amcharts, but the situation is likely to stem from a more generic javascript issue. Unfortunately it's being behind a development door; so no direct links. But, if I can paint the picture:-

1) Main index page uses jQuery.load() function to load a page of analytics and information.
2) Once loaded; jQuery.getScript() is used to fetch graph data.
3) Nothing appears

The same code works when together in one single static html page (i'm using example data just to get it running right now). It doesn't even work when I put it all in the .load()'d file together.

I've taken it further up the loading tree, so it's all in the main index page, no loading() bits. Still nothing.

**However**, if I go forward on the browser, then back. The graph is there... ready to go. Any ideas what might be leading to this behaviour?

Any thoughts, directions of investigation very, very welcome.

Comment: Use Firefox + Frebug, open the NET tab and see if you get any load errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overcome this by using an iframe to load the graphs, not idea but workable solution.